# "TypeError: element['animate'] is not a function" error on ios device, after upgrading to angular v13

Tags: angular, angular13, ionic6

We decided to upgrade our ionic app to angular v13.2.3 and to @ionic/angular v6.0.8. After the upgrade, the app was running without any problems in the browser and on android.
As we tested it on ios the app was starting, but wasn't showing any content and we got this error:

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found a solution for this. The error was caused, because my ios version wasn't supported anymore. Angular is only supporting the last 2 major versions of safari meaning the v14 and 15. My device is running on v13.

The element animate api is only available for versions higher than v13.1.For Versions below you can use this [web-animations-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-animations-js)

Found this issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45016

What you can do to fix this, is adding or uncommenting this part below in your `polifills.ts` file:

[image]

Then you can run `npm install --save web-animations-js` to install the animation package.

Now the app should work again.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to disable animations for old browsers.

```
const disableAnimations =
  !('animate' in document.documentElement)
  || (navigator && /iPhone OS (8|9|10|11|12|13)_/.test(navigator.userAgent));


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule.withConfig({ disableAnimations }),
...
```

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45016#issuecomment-1046013903